# How to improve intuitive feeling for rhythm

Tags: guitar, rhythm

I'm playing for around 10 years now and I'm definitely not a beginner. Still, my intuitive understanding of new rhythms is very poor.

I can learn to play nearly every rhythm if I have enough time. This is a very analytical process like breaking everything down in small blocks, practice them super slow and connect them.

Even this works it's not a useful approach if someone shows you a new song and ask you to play a backing for a singer. It doesn't has to be perfect but it should catch the idea of the rhythm of the song. Very often I must respond with: Sorry, I have to practice this first.

Other musicians in my circle of acquaintances don't have this problem. They don't care a lot about the theory behind it, they just start playing and it sounds good.
How do I reach this point? Of course I asked them but I never got a satisfying answer, they just do it without thinking about it.

I'm already doing a lot of these classic rhythm exercises like pyramid, shifting accents, syncopation, ... with a metronome. And of course this helps but this alone does not take me to point where I want to go.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you already have straight 8th notes and straight quarter notes down intuitively? How about running dotted 8th -> 16th note patterns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercises to get beter at rhythm (piano)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109578/exercises-to-get-beter-at-rhythm-piano). And numerous other questions on leaning rhythm.

Comment: Actually, how often have you done those sight reading clapping ear test exercises? They're standard fare in piano lessons or at least preparing for Royal Conservatory of Music (RCM) exams. (They had me sight reading and clapping 8th-note triplets and regular 8th notes in the same exercise by Grade 10.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci Straight notes are not a problem. I have a bunch of dotted patterns in my repertoire but not very single possible one. If I encounter a new  one most times I have to spent some hours to get it right.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I've done them in different levels. But still its just learning patterns. I dont have the feeling it helps me that much with understanding new stuff.

Comment: Note that "playing for 10 years" is not *that much*. It depends on how those 10 years were spent in studying and education. It would help to know how you approached playing, if you ever had any theory course (with/without teacher, in a class or individually), how your instrument training evolved along with the theoretical comprehension (and I don't mean about the "rules" and pure notions of music theory) and, not less important, at what age you started. Most of the times, this kind of problems are caused by inappropriate education in early years, failing to address primary elements of music »

Comment: » learning, such as ear training, inner ear, rhythmic/tonal abstraction, time/interval relations etc. All that is often (and with good reasons) done through use of the voice, which is the most intuitive and autonomic way we have to approach music. So, the first question would be: when you have difficulties understanding a rhythm, before trying on the instrument, are you able to "replay" it with your voice? If you are, then you're probably half-way, as it means that you don't actually have issues in understanding the rhythm, but only in "connecting" the part of your brain that actually plays.

Comment: I started with age of 20 and play on average ~2-3h a day (but not all time is practice). I'm mainly self taught, but had done also some lessons. I have a solid knowledge of music theory and this helps a lot with identifying harmonic context, notes, chords... but not so much with feeling a rhythm.

Comment: If I have a tricky rhythm I can't deal with then it doesn't matter if I try to strum it, knock it on the table or sing it.

Comment: I’m curious what kind of answer you’re looking for. I myself do not have an intuitive understanding of rhythms but I’ve learned enough of the most popular rhythms that I can pick up new rhythms and feel them quite quickly. I’ve never done rhythm exercises so I don’t know if those help, but I’m a little skeptical. Learning rhythms will help you with understanding rhythms.

Comment: Can you dance to any random tune? Not very well necessarily, but well enough so you feel you’re moving to the music? Or can you tap along to a song while driving a car? Doing these kinds of things might help you develop a more intuitive sense for rhythm on guitar.

Answer (score 2):

There are no shortcuts:

- Practice sight reading rhythms. There are books and web sites available for sight reading practice.
- Learn a lot of rhythms. Do a web search for something like "rhythms every drummer should know" and learn to strum the results on guitar. You’ll have to count and subdivide and use a metronome to get them right before you can just feel them.
- Listen to a lot of music that has percussion and popular rhythms in it. The previous web search should also lead you to examples and names of rhythms to search for.

Be aware that if you don’t recognize a rhythm on the page you’ll have to sight read it to hear it and then get in the groove of it. Until or unless you can audiate a rhythm before you play (sight reading practice will help with this), you’ll have to get the groove from the first few times you play it and try to settle in as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not looking for shortcuts, I'm looking for a different (additional) approach. Like I said, I know multiple musicians which are not able to sight read at all nor do any rhythm exercise on a regular base but can still adapt rhythms super fast. So there has to be another way of doing this.

Comment: @flappix Ok if you don’t like my answer that’s fine. I’m a guitarist who can just look at some chords and get the rhythm and play and sing and direct the rest of the band all at the same time and this is how I learned to do all that so I thought maybe it would help you. Have you tried asking these other people how they learned to do it?

Comment: Yes, like I wrote in the initial post. They tell me something like "Dont think about it, dont count it, just feel it." Unfortunately I dont feel it.

Comment: @flappix I hope someone else posts an answer you like. The advice to “don’t think about it” is one of the shortcuts I was saying there isn’t. I wasn’t suggesting you are looking for a shortcut.

Comment: @flappix regarding your first comment, the first thing Todd says is “There are no Shortcuts.” He then gives you 3 good ideas to work on. Do you know how to read music or much about theory?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Yes, I do. I've already done these exercises (and still working on them). The basic strategy behind all this is to learn as much patterns as possible to lower the risk of encounter new patterns. It's valid, it's working in many cases, but it is not flexible. This is not a bad answer but it's not the answer to my question.

Comment: @flappix Part 2 of his answer is to learn patterns. Part 1, sight reading is not about memorizing, it is about reacting and having to play something you don’t know on the spot, which ultimately helps in recognizing and playing unfamiliar rhythms quickly. As for part 3, I would add transcribing things you haven’t played before. I would also suggest listening to and playing along with recordings you like. Since you don’t have the ability to do it without thinking about it like your acquaintances your best choice is to work hard to know exactly what you’re doing.

Comment: @flappix "The basic strategy behind all this is to learn as much patterns as possible to lower the risk of encounter new patterns" That is a good summary of how we learn **everything**. There is literally no other way that I've ever known to learn things. This is how we learn languages, mathematics, science, music, etc. I think you might have left something out though: Once we learn enough patterns, we can encounter a new pattern that is *similar* (but not identical) to *one or more* patterns that we have already learned and then we can quickly synthesize the new pattern from what we know.

Comment: Not wishing to disagree with you, but I do. As a young 11yo, learning guitar, I knew nothing about the technicality of rhythms, or the theory behind them, and certainly didn't learn as many patterns as I could. It just happened. No-one taught me how to do it. Serendipity? Maybe. Now, knowing a bit of theory, I can understand what I do, but in the moment, never think about it. Problem is, I can't come up with an answer to OP's question!

Comment: @Tim Clearly it didn’t just happen for the asker or they wouldn’t be asking. It doesn’t always just happen. When it doesn’t, the only way I’ve ever found to make it happen is to do the work.

Comment: @flappix ok, read it as "there are no magic ways."    The more you practice as many rhythms as possible (with a metronome, preferably), the more those rhythms will be ingrained.   Same as learning scales and arpeggios.